# R mutiple events in 1 group

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I'm working on a school project and I'm trying to show the difference between driving and standing still in percentage. Now I got multiple events like break time, loading, unloading and stopping where a truck driver is standing still. I have for every event the total time the driver spent time on it:
[image: time per event per day]

Now I want to group the laden = loading, lossen = unloading, pauzeren = break time and stoppen = stopping to one group as standing still. How do I make this group in Rstudio so I can calculate how many percent the driver is standing still and how many percent a driver is driving on a day

Answer (score 0):

On way I can think of is to create a new variable e.g. `IfStanding`:

```
df$IfStanding = ifelse(df$event %in% c("stoppen"), 1, 0)
```

or `Motion`:

```
df$Motion = ifelse(df$event %in% c("stoppen","laden","lossen","pauzeren"),
                   "Standing", "NotStanding")
```

Then you can use the new variable to aggregate the data.

Comment: It gives me the folowing error: Error in dfmerge %>% group_by(dateFormat) %>% mutate(verschil = difftime(timeFormat,  : 
  could not find function "%>%<-" But i do have the pipe symbol at the end of this line.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this. It seems you had a typo "%>%<-" which caused this error.

Comment: If I run my code before the df$motion it does work and give me the table as seen in the picture